# Sending data to one activity to another activity with volley

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

I have an activity that makes a connection with an php file. that php file needs an ean to work. so I need to send the ean code from my input field in my main activity to my second activity so I can send it to php but I could get it to work. this is what I have:

```
//            Intent productInfo = new Intent(mainActivity.this, androidProductRequest.class);
//            productInfo.putExtra("ean",ean.getText().toString());
//            startActivity(productInfo);
            androidProductRequest androidProductRequest = new androidProductRequest(Integer.parseInt(ean.getText().toString()));
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(androidProductRequest);
```

at first I thought maybe it will work when I send it with intent but then I saw that u need to do an something with requestqueue but couldn't figure out what exactly. this is what I have on the second activity:

```
package com.example.productfinder;

import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class androidProductRequest extends mainActivity {
    public void androidProductRequest (final String ean){
        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = "My_url";
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Volley Demo");
            final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("VOLLEY1", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    return params;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Is ean.getText() is always a String?

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala no its always a Integer, I just put String there for now just to test it out